# Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: with AudioCache

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a little sound in a flutter app, I'm using AudioCache for it, here is part of the code:

```
  AudioCache player = AudioCache(prefix: 'assets/');
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    player = AudioCache(prefix: 'assets/',fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));
  }
```

then I used in other part of the code, I called like this:

```
player.play('prueba.mp3');
```

Then throws this error:

```
E/flutter (13057): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/prueba.
mp3
E/flutter (13057): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
E/flutter (13057): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13057): #1      AudioCache._fetchAsset (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:75:29)
E/flutter (13057): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:82:30)
E/flutter (13057): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13057): #3      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:97:37)
E/flutter (13057): #4      AudioCache.getAbsoluteUrl (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:192:23)
E/flutter (13057): #5      AudioCache.play (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:122:24)
E/flutter (13057): #6      _Timer_Page.startNextTimer.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:proyecto/timerPage
.dart:99:18)
E/flutter (13057): #7      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1244:30)
E/flutter (13057): #8      _Timer_Page.startNextTimer.<anonymous closure> (package:proyecto/timerPage.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (13057): #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13057): #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13057): #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13057): #12     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1042:26)
E/flutter (13057): #13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (13057): #14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13057): #15     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1026:26)
E/flutter (13057): #16     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter (13057): #17     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter (13057): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (13057):
```

the pubspec.yaml is like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_picker: ^1.1.5
  sqflite: ^1.3.2
  audioplayers: ^0.17.0
  file_picker: ^1.5.0

assets:
  - assets/prueba.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the correct file name to `play`.

```
player.play('prueba.mp3');
```